# Get the first and the last row from one table

Tags: mysql, select

I want to get the first and the last row from a table.
Once i get that, i want to get another first and last row from another table.

Is some strange i think, but this is it.

please, maybe somebody can give me an advice for what i want.

This is where i'm stuck :

http://s14.postimage.org/sj9xgeofz/print.png

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:-

```
SELECT column name
 FROM table1
 WHERE <conditions>
 ORDER BY date DESC
 LIMIT 1
 UNION
 SELECT column name
 FROM table1
 WHERE <conditions>
 ORDER BY date ASC
 LIMIT 1
```